# Is it allowed to scatter human cremains (ashes) from an aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, regulations

A serious question, here: There's gotta be a pilot out there somewhere who has done a memorial request to spray someone's ashes over a city street. I'm gonna do it out of spite for a lousy little mill town in Central Pa. There seems to be no laws against it on the books. 500' fly-overs are okay, spreading ashes falls under no FAA rule that I can find. When I go (soon, I'm an AO affected Vietnam Vet), I plan to have a contract with a crop-duster or acrobatic pilot for a decent show. Aside from (moral) advice, can someone comment, please? I wish to know of any known regulations governing this, especially any against.

Comment: Welcome to Av.se this site is [not really a forum but a QA site you can take a tour here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour). You have presented a discussion topic which is out of scope here but there are some real hard questions here. You may wish to reword to avoid this being closed out. Are you asking if its legal? Possible? Who to contact?

Comment: In many countries handling human remains is tightly restricted by law. This is more a legal question than an aviation one.

Comment: I have done it.  I hope it's legal!!!

Comment: When I was bush flying, the operator I worked for conducted that sort of operation.Built a dispenser made from a can with a remote release lid,which was clamped to the rear spreader bar of the floats.The pilot that took the plane to do the operation (over the deceased's favourite lake) decided that the contraption on the floats wasn't going to work and thought he could just take the ash container and hold it out the window of the C-180 (which hinged all the way up) and open the top. Abt 10 or 20% of the ashes ended up inside the cabin, where the deceased's wife was riding in the right seat.

Comment: For those who are working hard to close this question, on the basis this is not aviation related: If you close it, then the proper answer (which is FAA doesn't prohibit this, under certain conditions) will also disappear from the radar. It would be better to edit the question, to be more concise (the title says all).

Comment: Soon after 9/11 someone decided to scatter their loved ones ashes over the then-new Safeco Field in Seattle from an airplane. Unfortunately, the dispersal system malfunctioned and the bag of "powder" dropped onto the roof of the stadium. Hilarity ensued.... If you consider a full-blown hazardous material emergency hilarity. Apparently there was (possibly still is) a service in Seattle that will do this sort of thing for you.

Comment: All of your comments have been wonderful and very helpful. I am so glad some of you are able to appreciate the humor in my question; it was an FAA Regulation question--for the record. I served in the military, and worked with some absolutely top-notch pilots in Thailand during the rice wars. I would absolutely Love to connect with one who would do this for me. It will be carried out over Central Pa. Thanks men, God Bless you all. jim

Comment: @mins - **No one** is working hard to close the question, working hard implies a persistent active measure, one (or more) flagged the question, it then went to the democratic review queue, and those with the right rep had their say as they saw fit, for example you didn't vote leave open, which is your right not to vote -- but my logic says: FAA doesn't mind ≠ it is (or is not) allowed, thus it is not an aviation question as defined in the help center, in short: it's pointless to keep fighting over open/close in comments, IM-humble-O.

Comment: @ymb1: "*but my logic says: FAA doesn't mind ≠ it is (or is not) allowed, thus it is not an aviation question*" and how do you know FAA doesn't mind? Reading the answer here, else you wouldn't know. It's not like FAA doesn't mind the price of tomatoes. In the current question, it is *legitimate* to wonder if FAA has a rule about it. For tomatoes, we don't ask the question, we know with a large certainty, so it's not an aviation question.

Comment: @mins - All I want to clarify wrt your concern of valuable knowledge vanishing, consider that if the question is asked in the right place, e.g., Law.SE, everyone who is interested in such a topic will benefit more, more than the FAA has to say (which is nothing). I have no problem *whatsoever* with the community's final consensus (again, no one is working hard to close this topic), but note that voting opposite the final consensus doesn't make someone right or wrong. I'm also more than happy to discuss the logic in chat, not here.

Comment: @mins - I forgot to answer your first question, one would know from the first two comments (their aim is to explain why something could be off-topic – that's a good use of comments). A recent example is [a travel question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/60310/br61-taipeh-bangkok-vienna-why-the-deboarding-in-bangkok?noredirect=1#comment157920_60310) where I explained where to ask such a question, OP deleted it, thanked me, and asked on Travel.SE, and got their answer.

Answer (score 10):

AOPA has [an entire article](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2018/may/pilot/technique-spreading-ashes) on it that's worth reading and while it's generally fine with the FAA (assuming the pilot isn't being careless or reckless), there may be other regulations or laws that apply. The article mentions:

- Permission needed for scattering over federal land
- Permission needed for scattering over water (federal and local regulations)
- State burial requirements

But there are two specific aviation regulations that might apply to the flight. First, [14 CFR 91.15](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=3efaad1b0a259d4e48f1150a34d1aa77&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.10&idno=14#se14.2.91_115):

> **§91.15   Dropping objects.**
>
> No pilot in command of a civil aircraft may allow any object to be
>   dropped from that aircraft in flight that creates a hazard to persons
>   or property. However, this section does not prohibit the dropping of
>   any object if reasonable precautions are taken to avoid injury or
>   damage to persons or property.

Second, you said that you plan to have a "contract" with someone to scatter the ashes, which implies that you're going to pay the pilot. If that's the case, then the pilot may not use an experimental aircraft for the flight. That's because the FAA considers carrying human ashes to be carrying property ([Harris interpretation, 2009](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2009/harris%20-%20(2009)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf)) and [91.319(a)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1319) doesn't allow carrying property for compensation in experimental aircraft:

> (a) No person may operate an aircraft that has an experimental
>   certificate—
>
> (1) For other than the purpose for which the certificate was issued;
>   or
>
> (2) Carrying persons or property for compensation or hire.

Finally, note that accidents can and do happen [and in at least one case two people died while spreading ashes](https://app.ntsb.gov/pdfgenerator/ReportGeneratorFile.ashx?EventID=20160325X80001&AKey=1&RType=HTML&IType=FA) (although to be fair, the toxicology data was fairly 'interesting' in that one).

Comment: Actually, that statute raises some interesting examples. Over some municipal areas of regulation, it's not legal, and especially over a town... it's a little shady probably in the legal area. For example, Faye Rich (Ben Rich of the Skunk Works' wife) wanted her ashes spread over their ranch, but it was illegal. Considering they owned the ranch, and you want to drop ashes over a town, you might want to hit up the local ATC or FAA officials. jic you know?

Comment: @Jihyun Thanks for the feedback, I expanded my answer with more information. This is one of those areas where the FAA doesn't care much but other regulators might.